# How to implement Union-Find using linked lists?

Tags: java, list, union-find

I need to write a piece of code using the Kruskal algorithm, which in turn needs the Union-Find algorithm.

This includes the methods Make-Set(x), Find-Set(x) and Union(x, y).
I need to implement them using linked lists, but I am not sure of how to start with the Make-Set method.

The Make-Set Method should create a set and make the first element into a key (to compare sets). How exactly would I declare a key using linked lists?

---

Shortly put: How do I implement this pseudo code for linked lists in Java?

Make-Set(x)
x.p = x

x.rank = 0

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've heard this referred to in the past not as "Union-Find" but as a disjoint set. It isn't exactly a linked list, since the nodes do have a link, but they aren't necessarily linked up in a linear fashion. It's more like a tree where each node has a pointer to its parent and you can walk up the tree to the root.

I don't have much time right now, but here's a quick sketch of how I would implement it in Java:

```
class Disjoint {
    Disjoint next;

    Disjoint findSet() {
        Disjoint head = this;
        if (next != null) {
            head = next.findSet();
            next = head;
        }
        return head;
    }

    void union(Disjoint other) {
        Disjoint us = this.findSet();
        Disjoint them = other.findSet();
        us.next = them;
    }
}
```

Creating an instance is your Make-Set. What you call Find-Set I would call find head or find leader, maybe find identity. I've called it `findSet` here, though. It walks the chain to find the root of the tree. It also performs an optional operation; it snaps all the links on the way back out of the recursive call so that they all point directly at the root. This is an optimization to keep the chains short.

Finally, Union is implemented just by assigning one root's `next` pointer to point at the other set. I'm not sure what you intended with `rank`; if it's the size of the set, you can add a field for that and simply sum them when you union two sets. But you initialize it to `0` for a new set when I would expect it to be initialized to `1`.

Two nodes `a` and `b` belong to the same set if `a.findSet() == b.findSet()`. If you need the nodes to carry some data, make the class generic and provide the data to the constructor, and add a getter:

```
class Disjoint<T> {
    Disjoint<T> next;
    T data;

    public Disjoint(final T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    // rest of class identical except Disjoint replaced with Disjoint<T> everywhere

}
```